# On GitHub API - what is the best way to get the last commit message associated with each file?

Tags: github, comments, github-api

So far as I understand it, messages are associated with commits. But when you look at a repo on GitHub it helpfully lists the message by each file, for when it was last changed.

I'd like to replicate that in a web view of a repo I have. Looking at the GitHub api it looks to me the only way to get that info is to download *all* the commits (which can be paged), and work from the most recent ones assigning commit messages to the files in your local cache, going further and further back until you've got the message for every file, potentially to the very first commit, if any of the files have not been changed since the initial commit

Question is, is that the right way to do it? Is that not going to kill even the 5000/hr quota?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you want to achieve. Do you want to get (1) the latest comment for a file, no matter which commit this comment is associated with? Or do you want to get (2) the latest comment in the latest commit for a file? The difference is that a file might have comments associated in several commits, and the latest comment might not be in the latest commit because someone might comment on the file in a previous commit. So, which of these options is what you want?

Comment: I want option 1, please :) Just as it shows you in the web view on GitHub itself.

Comment: Where does it show you that in the web view on GitHub? Can you give me an exact URL as an example? When you go to a project site on GitHub, it shows you the commit messages for the files (e.g. the list of files when you go to https://github.com/github/developer.github.com), not the commit comments. Commit messages and commit comments are two different things. I apologize if I misunderstood you, just want to clarify what it is that you need exactly. :)

Comment: I would like exactly as per the link you mentioned. I just want commit messages, not 'comments'. CLearly, I didn't know there was such a distinction.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Ok, after figuring out that what you need is the latest commit message for each file, here's what you can do.

First, get the list of files in your repository. To do this, you need to:

1) [fetch the reference object](http://developer.github.com/v3/git/refs/#get-a-reference) of the branch that you want to list files for:

```
GET https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/git/refs/heads/:branch
```

You probably want the master branch, so this is an example of the request you will make:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/izuzak/pmrpc/git/refs/heads/master
```

The response you will get will look like this:

```
{
  "ref": "refs/heads/master",
  "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/izuzak/pmrpc/git/refs/heads/master",
  "object": {
    "sha": "fd6973f430a3367ad718ff049f1b075843913d6f",
    "type": "commit",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/izuzak/pmrpc/git/commits/fd6973f430a3367ad718ff049f1b075843913d6f"
  }
}
```

2) [fetch the commit object](http://developer.github.com/v3/git/commits/#get-a-commit) that the reference points to, using the `object.url` property of the response you received in the previous step:

```
GET https://api.github.com/repos/izuzak/pmrpc/git/commits/fd6973f430a3367ad718ff049f1b075843913d6f
```

The response you will get will look like this:

```
{
  "sha": "fd6973f430a3367ad718ff049f1b075843913d6f",
  "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/izuzak/pmrpc/git/commits/fd6973f430a3367ad718ff049f1b075843913d6f",
  "html_url": "https://github.com/izuzak/pmrpc/commits/fd6973f430a3367ad718ff049f1b075843913d6f",
  "author": {
    "name": "Ivan Zuzak",
    "email": "izuzak@gmail.com",
    "date": "2013-04-09T08:55:45Z"
  },
  "committer": {
    "name": "Ivan Zuzak",
    "email": "izuzak@gmail.com",
    "date": "2013-04-09T08:55:45Z"
  },
  "tree": {
    "sha": "f5f5de80f67dd794ffbd4abb855fb7d1a573660e",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/izuzak/pmrpc/git/trees/f5f5de80f67dd794ffbd4abb855fb7d1a573660e"
  },
  "message": "fix typos",
  "parents": [
    {
      "sha": "d3617ae56dda793131e743b2ff394984bbab6ca3",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/izuzak/pmrpc/git/commits/d3617ae56dda793131e743b2ff394984bbab6ca3",
      "html_url": "https://github.com/izuzak/pmrpc/commits/d3617ae56dda793131e743b2ff394984bbab6ca3"
    }
  ]
}
```

3) [fetch the tree object](http://developer.github.com/v3/git/trees/#get-a-tree) of the commit object fetched in the previous step. You will do this by following the `tree.url` link provided in the response of the previous step:

```
GET https://api.github.com/repos/izuzak/pmrpc/git/trees/f5f5de80f67dd794ffbd4abb855fb7d1a573660e
```

The response will look like this:

```
{
  "sha": "f5f5de80f67dd794ffbd4abb855fb7d1a573660e",
  "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/izuzak/pmrpc/git/trees/f5f5de80f67dd794ffbd4abb855fb7d1a573660e",
  "tree": [
    {
      "mode": "100644",
      "type": "blob",
      "sha": "726f21a4adec8c24c2fab6cf5b455d094a8b21bf",
      "path": "LICENSE.markdown",
      "size": 568,
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/izuzak/pmrpc/git/blobs/726f21a4adec8c24c2fab6cf5b455d094a8b21bf"
    },
    {
      "mode": "100644",
      "type": "blob",
      "sha": "eb94760b81441b34a73d1b085d9f153ae48b0e63",
      "path": "README.markdown",
      "size": 5772,
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/izuzak/pmrpc/git/blobs/eb94760b81441b34a73d1b085d9f153ae48b0e63"
    },
    {
      "mode": "040000",
      "type": "tree",
      "sha": "2e72b217b8644ce6874cda03387a7ab2d8eee55e",
      "path": "examples",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/izuzak/pmrpc/git/trees/2e72b217b8644ce6874cda03387a7ab2d8eee55e"
    },
    {
      "mode": "100644",
      "type": "blob",
      "sha": "64b0dbe4981759c0f9640c8e882c97c7324fc798",
      "path": "pmrpc.js",
      "size": 24546,
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/izuzak/pmrpc/git/blobs/64b0dbe4981759c0f9640c8e882c97c7324fc798"
    }
  ]
}
```

These are all the files and folders in the repository. Notice however that for folders you will need to recursively fetch the folder tree object to get the list of files in the folder. In the response above, the `examples` is a folder which you can see by the tree value of the type property. So, you would to another GET request on the url provided with the folder:

```
  GET https://api.github.com/repos/izuzak/pmrpc/git/trees/2e72b217b8644ce6874cda03387a7ab2d8eee55e
```

An alternative approach is to get the list of **all files** (in all folders) with just one request, using the `recursive=1` parameter, as described [here](http://developer.github.com/v3/git/trees/#get-a-tree-recursively). I suggest you use this approach since it requires just a single HTTP request.

Next, now that you have the list of files and folders in the repo, you will [get the last commit](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#list-commits-on-a-repository) that changed each of the files/folders. To do that, make this request

```
GET https://api.github.com/repos/:user/:repo/commits?path=FILE_OR_FOLDER_PATH
```

So, for example, this is a request to fetch the commits for the `examples` folder mentioned above:

```
GET https://api.github.com/repos/izuzak/pmrpc/commits?path=examples
```

The response you will get is a list of commit object, and you should just look at the first object in that list (since you are interested in the last commit for the file) and retrieve the `commit.message` property to get the message you need:

```
[
  {
    "sha": "3437f015257683a86e3b973b3279754df9ac2b24",
    "commit": {
      "author": { ... },
      "committer": { ... },
      "message": "change mode",
      "tree": { ... },
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/izuzak/pmrpc/git/commits/3437f015257683a86e3b973b3279754df9ac2b24",
      "comment_count": 0
    },
    ...
  },
  {
    ...
  }
]
```

In this case, the message for the latest commit that changed the folder `examples` is "change mode."

So, basically, you need to make 3 HTTP requests to fetch the list of files, and then 1 HTTP request for each file and folder. The bad news is that if you have lots of files -- you will be making lots of HTTP requests. The good news is that you can cache responses so that you don't need to make requests if nothing changed (see [here](http://developer.github.com/v3/#conditional-requests) for more info). Also, you will not be fetching all the commit messages at once, you will fetch them as the user navigates through the folders (just as on GitHub as you click on folders). Thus you should be able to stay within limits of 5000 requests easily.

Hope this helps! And let me know if you find an easier way to do this :). I don't know if theres a way to achieve this with just 1-2 requests, which is probably what you expected.

Comment: Ticked as the answer as it's very comprehensive, thanks. However, it's  the call to get the last commit for every file that I was hoping to avoid. I think what I'll do is have a background cron job that gets a few every so often, limiting the rate it does so. It's not crucial information, but it is useful I think

Comment: @MarcosScriven Thanks! And yeah, I understand why that's an issue for you. The cron job idea sounds cool, though. Nice!

Comment: Nice! If you just want the latest commit that affected the file, you can use pagination to work for you like so `GET https://api.github.com/repos/izuzak/pmrpc/commits?path=examples&page=1&per_page=1`

Comment: What if repo is private?

Answer (score 3):

I'm listing commits on the repository and than grabbing the first one and reading it's SHA and it works great:

https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#list-commits-on-a-repository

In Go it looks something like this:

```
func GetLatestCommit(owner, repo string, sgc *github.Client) (string, error) {
    commits, res, err := sgc.Repositories.ListCommits(owner, repo, &github.CommitsListOptions{})

    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("err: %s res: %s", err, res)
        return "", err
    }

    log.Printf("last commit: %s", *commits[0].SHA)

    return *commits[0].SHA, nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In search of building permanent links, I found one of the easiest way to retrieve the commit sha is to actually parse the html page.

Benefits:

- all file/folder pages in a repository have it, even the root
- single HTTP call
- no auth login needed
- will use the right branch (some don't use master as default)
- works on branches too

There is a link called `Permalink` on every file page.
If you are looking for ways to identify that link
there is the class `.js-permalink-shortcut` and also the `data-hotkey="y"` attribute, as described in [Getting permanent links to files - Github](https://help.github.com/articles/getting-permanent-links-to-files/#press-y-to-permalink-to-a-file-in-a-specific-commit).

```
<a href="/luckydonald/JavaPipBoyServer/blob/a6f4038336ff41463ad527b4ff4fda45642ebc6d/PROTOCOL.md" class="d-none js-permalink-shortcut" data-hotkey="y">Permalink</a>
```

So in this example the sha is `a6f4038336ff41463ad527b4ff4fda45642ebc6d`.

Note, it will always be rendered, even if you are already on that commit.

In case somebody likes to build a permalink from it, the url hash (e.g. line references like [`#L437-L441`](https://github.com/luckydonald/JavaPipBoyServer/blob/a6f4038336ff41463ad527b4ff4fda45642ebc6d/src/main/java/de/luckydonald/pipboyserver/PipBoyServer/Database.java#L437-L441)) needs to be kept (appended) manually.