# how can i find a commit which i searched on github api?

Tags: javascript, github, fetch, github-api

I am developing an extension for github. I need search a commit. I'm using github api, firstly i tried get all commits on api but max value of perpage is 100. Secondly i tried `https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}/commits?q={commit_message}` but it doesn't work. So how can I find a commit i'm looking for in github api?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [search commit API](https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/searching-on-github/searching-commits). It's flexible enough to search by different qualifiers, like committer username, author, repository, organization, etc.

Take into account, there is a time limit for running your search, in case you exceed the time limit, the API returns the matches that were already found prior to the timeout, and the response has the **incomplete_results** property set to true, read more about it [here](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/search#timeouts-and-incomplete-results)

Here's an example using [Octokit](https://octokit.github.io/rest.js/v18#search-commits) that searches inside GitHub org the **test** string

| Search GitHub commit message | [<kbd>Run locally [image]</kbd>](https://runme.dev/api/runme?repository=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fdegrammer%2Fstack-overflow-answers.git&fileToOpen=github/search-commit-message.md) |
| --- | --- |

```js
const text = 'test';
const org = 'github';
const query =`${text} org:${org}`;
const searchResult = await github.rest.search.commits({
  q: query
});
  
// In case there is a timeout running the query, you can use incomplete_results to check if there are likely more results
// for your query, read more here https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/search#timeouts-and-incomplete-results
const { items, total_count} = searchResult.data;
console.log(items.map(commit => commit.commit));
console.log(`Found ${total_count} commits for ${text} at GitHub org called ${org}`);
```

Comment: Thanks that works.

Answer (score 0):

Read this: [GitHub API Docs](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/commits#get-a-commit-comment)
In the original documentation it says to use get `get /repos/{owner}/{repo}/commits`. The error may be caused by this. You should go through the documentation again.

```js
await octokit.request('GET /repos/{owner}/{repo}/commits', {
  owner: 'octocat',
  repo: 'hello-world'
})
```

```json
[
  {
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/commits/6dcb09b5b57875f334f61aebed695e2e4193db5e",
    "sha": "6dcb09b5b57875f334f61aebed695e2e4193db5e",
    "node_id": "MDY6Q29tbWl0NmRjYjA5YjViNTc4NzVmMzM0ZjYxYWViZWQ2OTVlMmU0MTkzZGI1ZQ==",
    "html_url": "https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World/commit/6dcb09b5b57875f334f61aebed695e2e4193db5e",
    "comments_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/commits/6dcb09b5b57875f334f61aebed695e2e4193db5e/comments",
    "commit": {
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/git/commits/6dcb09b5b57875f334f61aebed695e2e4193db5e",
      "author": {
        "name": "Monalisa Octocat",
        "email": "support@github.com",
        "date": "2011-04-14T16:00:49Z"
      },
      "committer": {
        "name": "Monalisa Octocat",
        "email": "support@github.com",
        "date": "2011-04-14T16:00:49Z"
      },
      "message": "Fix all the bugs",
      "tree": {
        "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/tree/6dcb09b5b57875f334f61aebed695e2e4193db5e",
        "sha": "6dcb09b5b57875f334f61aebed695e2e4193db5e"
      }
```

If you examine the Respons you can see the message column, maybe this will help. I also found this in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15933109) `GET https://api.github.com/repos/izuzak/pmrpc/commits?path=examples&page=1&per_page=1`

Comment: It doesn't work for me because i need without per page parameter get all commits or search by commit message.